# excel vba concat number with leading zero and text in new cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have copied a cell using vba that is formatted as Custom "00000"

e.g. 07455

when I try to copy this value the active cell and concat with text, I loose the leading zero.
here's the code i'm using -

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Value = "WO-" & ws.Range("B12").Value
```

I've tried formatting the destination (active cell) as Custom "00000" but it I still loose the zero.

I end up with **WO-7455**  instead of **WO-07455**

Can anyone help please?

thanks
Craig

Comment: you can set the formatting to `Text` to avoid any automatic actions done by excel (e.g. to not lose leading zeros or to not try to parse a date when entered). You can also enter values that start with a `=` and are not a formula this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Value = "WO-" & ws.Range("B12").Text
```

or (not tested)

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Value = "WO-" & Format(ws.Range("B12").Value,"00000")
```

**EDIT:** Note that the first option will show whatever the source cell (`B12`) displays.  So if the column is so narrow that the display is `##` or hidden, the result cell may not display what you expect.  The second option should always work, no matter the column width of the source cell.

Comment: the `(not tested)` is preferable and I've just tested it to confirm that it works.

Comment: @CraigJohnstone The only issue with Option 1 is that, if your column is narrow such that the value shows as `###`, at the time you run the macro, that is what you will see in `B1`. The second option may be more bullet-proof.

Comment: @reportgunner Thank you.  And I've added an Edit indicating why the second option may be preferable.

Comment: I prefer the 2nd option too :)